# Payment method doesnt show on invoice

Tags: invoice, payment, pdf

Payments method are visible in backend-printed invoices, but on custom front-end function field `payment` is blank, any suggestions?

No templete files were edited.

Controller responsible of printing invoices:

```
public function downloadPdfAction()
{
    $invoiceId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
    if ($invoiceId) {
        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId);
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    } else {
        $orderId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    }

    if ($this->_canViewOrder($order)) {

        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        if (isset($invoice)) {
            Mage::register('current_invoice', $invoice);
            $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
        } else {
            $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
            $invoicesSet = array();
            foreach ($invoices as $_invoice) {
                array_push($invoicesSet, $_invoice);
            }

            $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoicesSet);
        }

        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
            '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
    } else {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/history');
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('sales/guest/form');
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

try following function to fetch payment method title

> $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();

Comment: i've put `$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();` as first line inside $this->_canViewOrder block, no result. Same for `$invoice->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle()`

var_dump of these result in correct payment name

Comment: Worked for me, +1

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. I'm using this code.

```
if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceIds[0])) {
            $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
            $pdf->render();
            $pdf->save(Mage::getBaseDir(). DS . "var". DS. "email_invoice". DS .$this->getIncrementId()."-invoice.pdf");

}
```

Payment method section is blank when pdf generating. Any thought?

Thanks in advance.